# Changing Windows User Name

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is there a way to change the Window User name? I know if you go into the control panel and change it the display name will change but it still keeps the original name like under C:\Users\ or when you launch the command promt. Is there a way to change that as well?

Answer (score 2):

Run [Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer) to backup all data and settings. Now create a new user account with the new correct name log into this account, run `Windows Easy Transfer` again and import the settings from the first run of `Windows Easy Transfer`. After this is completed, delete the first account and the user folder.

Comment: This does not address the issue of changing the user name of an existing account.